# How can i add pin numbers to opamp circuit in circuitikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

[image]

Here is the sample code for a simple voltage follower using LM741.I need to add pin numbers for the opamp circuit.How is it possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, calc}
\begin{document}

\ctikzset{tripoles/op amp/height=2.0, tripoles/op amp/width=2.5,}

\tikzset{opamp label/.style={xshift=-9mm, font=\normalsize,right}}
\tikzset{iovardelay/.style={label={[above]90:\textsf{#1}},
                        label={[right=2ex]180:\textsf{I}},
                        label={[left=3ex]0:\textsf{O}},
                        draw,fill=blue!10,
                        minimum width=1cm,
                        minimum height=2cm
                        }
    }
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp){}(opamp)node[opamp label]{LM741}

 (opamp.-) |- ($(opamp.-)+(0.2,2)$) to[short] ($(opamp.-)+(2.2,2)$) -|
 (opamp.out) to[short,*-] ($(opamp.out)+(.5,0)$) node [right] {$V_{out}$} node [ocirc] {} 
(opamp.+) to[short]  ($(opamp.+)-(0,.5)$) to [sV]++(0,-2) node[ground] {}

(opamp.down) ++ (0,-.5) node[below] {${-15V}$}-- (opamp.down)
(opamp.up) ++ (0,.5) node[above] {${+15V}$}-- (opamp.up)
 ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[PH/.append style={font=\scriptsize,inner ysep=2pt,inner xsep=5pt},
                   PV/.append style={PH,inner ysep=2pt,inner xsep=2pt}]
\node [op amp,label=center:LM741] (opamp) {};
\draw (opamp.-) node [PH,above right] {2} % pin number
                |- ($(opamp.out)+(0,2)$)
                to [short,-*] (opamp.out)   node [PH,above left] {6} % pin number
                to [short,-o]   ++ (0.5,0)  node [right] {$V_{\mathrm{out}}$}
    (opamp.+)   node [PH,above right] {3} % pin number
                to [sV]         ++ (0,-2)   node [ground] {}
    (opamp.up)  node[PV,above right] {1} % pin number
                to [short,-o]  ++ (0,.5)    node [above] {${+15V}$}
    (opamp.down)node[PV,below right] {8} % pin number
                to [short,-o]  ++ (0,-.5)   node [below] {${-15V}$}
                ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

i don't remember correct pin numbers, so you check them and accordingly correct if necessary.